# Maximal proper time for west coast metric, and minimal proper time for east coast metric?

Tags: special-relativity

The action for special relativity is

$$ Sq(t)]=\int \,d\tau . $$

Now, we there are two conventions:

1.) The west coast metric:

\begin{equation}  (d  s)^2 = (c d\tau)^2 =  (c d  t )^2 - (d  x )^2 - (d y )^2- (d  z )^2.\end{equation}

1.) The east coast metric:

\begin{equation}(d  s)^2 = (c d\tau)^2 =  - (c d  t )^2 + (d  x )^2 + (d y )^2+ (d  z )^2.\end{equation}

**Therefore, is it correct that if we use the west coast metric, the correct path is the path with *maximal* proper time, while if we use the east coast metric, it's the path with *minimal* proper time?**

Comment: The correct path is the one with **extremal** proper time.